# how to include another php file?

Tags: php

I have a php file, and I want to include another php file that have css link tags and javascript source tags, but when I try to include them, it doesn't get added to the page.

my php page:

```
<?php 
    $root = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/mysite'; 
    $theme = $root . '/includes/php/common.php';
    echo $theme;
    include($theme);
?>
```

common.php:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/main.css'/>";
```

Anyone know whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that `../css/main.css` exists?

Comment: use firebug and check which path it takes `href='../css/main.css'`.

Comment: if you're using chrome, you can press f12 > Console.

Comment: I checked the DOM of the page, and the link tag is not there.

Comment: If `include` fails to include the file, it will emit a warning. You should turn on error reporting.

Answer (score 7):

PHP's [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) is server-side, so you need to use the server side path. It is better to use `dirname(__FILE__)` instead of `$_SERVER['SSCRIPT_NAME']`, but `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` is absolutely wrong.

Try:

```
include dirname(__FILE__)."/common.php";
```

Or if the file you want to include is not on the same directory, change the path. For example for a parent directory, use `dirname(__FILE__)."/../common.php"`.

---

Note that some might suggest using `include "./common.php"` or similar. This *could* work, but will most likely **fail** when the script invoking `include` is actually being included by another script in another directory. Using `dirname(__FILE__)."/common.php"` will eliminate this problem.

Comment: This is helpful, but `dirname(__FILE__)` gets me the absolute path to the file, how can I get the absolute path to the root folder?

Comment: @omega I suppose you do not mean mean `/` the filesystem root on *nix systems or `C:\ ` on Windows. Usually you would use the relative path to the current script: use `../` for parent directory.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
<?php  
    $theme = 'includes/php/common.php';
    echo $theme;
    include($theme);
?>
```

If your includes folder is in the same folder as your php page then it should work, if not add you domain name instead. SERVER_NAME is not needed in this instance.