# Insert into file php code from other php file

Tags: php, variables, fputs

I'm trying to insert something like this php code:

```
<?php echo 'Hello world!'; ?>
```

using this script:

```
<?php
$code = '<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>';
$file = fopen('file.php', w)
fputs($file, $code);
fclose($file);
?>
```

in another .php file that the server will run when a client request the page.
is it possible to do? if it is, how?
i know you couldn't do it with this script but I don't know how can I do.
I don't need to print Hello word! In the new file I need the exactly code in the variable $code.

Comment: Put quotes around the `w` in `fopen()` and yes, you can do something just like what you have above. I've done it successfully many times. Did you try this before posting?

Comment: If you're just embedding one PHP file in another, can't you just include it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699973/how-to-include-another-php-file

Comment: What is the problem you have doing this? *Why* are you doing this? Dynamically creating new PHP files sounds like a bad idea typically.

Answer (score 1):

try it

```
$code = "<?php echo 'Hello world!'; ?>";
```

you need use double quotes to write this code

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

```
$code = '<?php echo \'Hello world!\'; ?>';
```

OR

```
$code = "<?php echo 'Hello world!'; ?>";
```

As in the comments you can see, put quotes around `w` and also `;` after `fopen()`:

```
$file = fopen('file.php', 'w');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<?php
$code = "<?php echo 'Hello world!'; ?>";
$file = fopen('file.php', 'w');
fputs($file, $code);
fclose($file);
?>
```

Comment: I need to insert the code in the variable $code. How can i do?

Comment: It doesn't work because it doesn't print anything on the screen but in the source of the page you can find <--!?php echo 'Hello word!'; ?--> like an HTML comment

Comment: What is the problem you have doing this?