# Diffrence Between Include And Include()

Tags: php

I heard there is a different between include vs include() ! is that true ?

for example

```
include "simple.php";
```

is different with ->

```
include("simple.php");
```

i asked for this from someone and he told me include() is calling include function but include without () is faster and is php In-Built !

i winder he is right or not !

is include "" faster than include("") ? i tried to search in Google and PHP references but i didn't find anything

Thanks.

Comment: From the docs - ***"Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument."*** They are exactly the same.

Comment: and see http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php#example-157

Comment: Whoever flagged this as opinion based probably didnt go through the PHP docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Include** is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

If you do:

```
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
```

this wont work, because it is evaluated as `include(('vars.php') == 'OK')`, i.e. `include('')`

*My advice:* Stick to `include example.php`. Keep it simple :)

Answer (score 1):

Because include is a special language construct, parentheses are not needed around its argument.

Just care when you compare return value :

```
<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Comment: How about including the source? :)

Comment: especially note the difference : 
`<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
?>`

Answer (score 1):

I think that include "" is just alias of include("") function. It makes code only a little bit shorter and easier to write. Basically, if there is difference between those two, it should be minimal.

Comment: Include is NOT a function :) But a language construct that mimics a function.

Answer (score 0):

They are both the same, `include` is a language construct with two different syntaxes.
You have the same behaviour with `echo`, `exit`, etc.

Comment: Are you mean die vs exit ? i think echo will be same behavior with print

Comment: die and exit are aliases. They have exactly the same behaviour. And, I apologize, parentheses on exit are required if you pass a return code - this is another little quirk of PHP.
And yes, echo and print have the both syntaxes.
All I wanted to say is, `echo`, `include`, `exit` and others are language constructs (and NOT functions) that let you choose between two different syntaxes.
**The "standard recommandation" in PHP is to use these language constructs without parentheses, as you can see in a lot of open-source PHP projects.**

Answer (score 0):

Basically **include ' '** is the main function of php to add the file but when you try to enter any file as like as like this form

```
 <?php
    $root = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/mysite'; 
        $theme = $root . '/includes/php/common.php';
        echo $theme;
        include($theme);
?>
```

then you need to used include function and also this is same logic in c language which you see at [how to include another php file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14699973/how-to-include-another-php-file)

Comment: what about include "$theme" ?

Comment: As you see that i am adding file through dir to dir not directly as like we are doing ...